# Reporting Services - set datasource dynamically, possibly via ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have some reporting services reports in 2005.

The use a shared data source in a rds file

Ideally I want them to use a connection string that is passed in from a configuration file, ideally via ASP.NETs ReportViewer control.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
DataSourceCredentials cred = new DataSourceCredentials();
cred.Name = 'credential_name';
cred.UserId = 'user_id';
cred.Password = 'password';


ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredential(new DataSourceCredentials[] { cred });
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

Comment: Is there a way I can actually set the server name here as well?

Comment: Yes ReportViewer1.ServerReport has proparty called ServerName or ServerUrl it was one or the outher 
Best Regards,
Iordan

Comment: I think the above solution is good for credentails, however what I wanted to do was dynamically set the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the connection string etc dynamically using expression based connection strings

See    http://blogs.msdn.com/bwelcker/archive/2005/04/29/413343.aspx

which uses the the same technique as below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156450.aspx (part about Expression-based Connection Strings)

**BUT, this is a bit pants as it means you cant preview your reports in the designer.**

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this task by passing in the connectionstring as a Report Parameter and then using the expression to point at the Report Parameter.

This requires the Excecution Account to be set in the SQLRS configuration and that account must be giving appropriate permissions on the database(s) it will be connecting.